# Namespaced classes causing problems with coverage report generation

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug, phing

Namespaced classes seem to be throwing Phing code coverage report generation for a loop. I'm getting a folder in the root of my project called `.%5Creports%5Ccoverage` that contains the .html files for any classes that are namespaced. All other classes generate the files in the proper directory as defined by `${reports.dir}/coverage`.

When viewing the report in the browser, the links to the class files are pointing to where they should be, but of course I get a 404 because the files themselves have been put in the wrong place. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Here are the relevant lines from each of my files:

build.properties:

```
base.dir = .
tests.dir = ${base.dir}/tests
reports.dir = ${base.dir}/reports
```

build.xml:

```
<!-- Run code coverage for PHP files -->
<target name="coverage">

    <coverage-setup database="${reports.dir}/coverage/coverage.db">
        <fileset refid="php-files" />
    </coverage-setup>

    <phpunit bootstrap="${tests.dir}/library/bootstrap.php" codecoverage="true">
        <batchtest>
            <fileset refid="tests" />
        </batchtest>
    </phpunit>

    <coverage-report outfile="${reports.dir}/coverage/coverage.xml">
        <report todir="${reports.dir}/coverage" />
    </coverage-report>

</target>

<!-- PHP files -->
<fileset dir="${application.dir}" id="php-files">
    <include name="**/*.php" />
</fileset>

<!-- Test files -->
<fileset dir="${tests.dir}/application" id="tests">
    <include name="**/*Test.php" />
</fileset>
```

Example namespaced class:

```
<?php

namespace GDI\WebService;

class PredictionRequest
{
    public $prefix;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You are talking about the code coverage report the phing task is generating and **not** the code coverage report phpunit can create for you?

Comment: @edorian, I'm referring to the reports that are generated by the coverage-report task.

Comment: Ok, just making sure it's not about the one that phpunit-code-coverage produces but the one that was written for the phing task so i don't spent time trying to reproduce the issues with the phpunit code base :)

Comment: @edorian Thanks for taking a look. I narrowed it down to a change in the Phing codebase that was supposed to fix another issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up tracking it down to this change http://www.phing.info/trac/changeset/1123/trunk/classes/phing/tasks/ext/coverage/CoverageReportTransformer.php. Edited phing/tasks/ext/coverage/CoverageReportTransformer.php to revert back to `$proc->setParameter('', 'output.dir', $dir->toString());` and everything is working great now. Not sure what 'efile' confusion the changeset is referring to, but nothing broke for me after the edit.